# How to substitute a big expression with a single variable in sympy

Tags: sympy

I have a sympy code which has a expression as follows

$$
z = \frac{x - 0.5}{\epsilon}
$$
$$
\phi = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}}
$$

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
z = symbols("z")
phi = 1/(1 + exp(-z))
phi_x = diff(phi,x)
```

After differentiation,  $\phi_x$ provides an expression

$$
\frac{e^{- \frac{x - 0.5}{\epsilon}}}{\epsilon \left(1 + e^{- \frac{x - 0.5}{\epsilon}}\right)^{2}}
$$

However, I just want to get the answer as below, where z is replaced for $(x - 0.5)/\epsilon$

$$
\frac{e^{-z}}{\epsilon \left(1 + e^{-z}\right)^{2}}
$$

I have tried both `phi_x.subs(x-0.5/eps, z)` and `phi_x.replace(x-0.5/eps, z)`. Both does not seems to give a proper subsitution as above.

Comment: Did you leave out the parentheses in `(x-0.5)/eps` also in the code that you ran?

Comment: If you want to obtain the last expression you could differentiate with respect to z instead of x in your code.